# Vulkan MESA-INTEL Warning

Tags: c++, ubuntu, vulkan

Currently using g++-11, on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Compiling using the flags: `-lvulkan -ldl -lSDL2main -lSDL2`.

I'm following this Vulkan tutorial: `https://vkguide.dev/docs/chapter-1/vulkan_init_code/`, where I'm up to the stage where we're supposed to build a Vulkan instance using the code shown below. However, when I run that portion of the code, I get the following warning:

`MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0`

Will this prevent me from moving on with the tutorial? How do I resolve the warning?

Code:

```
vkb::InstanceBuilder builder;

//make the Vulkan instance, with basic debug features
auto inst_ret = builder.set_app_name("Example Vulkan Application")
    .request_validation_layers(true)
    .require_api_version(1, 2, 0)
    .use_default_debug_messenger()
    .build();

vkb::Instance vkb_inst = inst_ret.value();

//store the instance
_instance = vkb_inst.instance;
//store the debug messenger
_debug_messenger = vkb_inst.debug_messenger;
```